# On the positiveness of a convolution product

Tags: convolution, deconvolution

I've the following question:

Assume that $f(t),g(t)\in L^2[0;+\infty)$ and $f(t)$ is causal and positive $\forall t > 0$. Consider the convolution operation

$$\int_0^{+\infty} f(\tau)g(t-\tau) d\tau = y(t)$$

Is there any "compact" way to state the necessary conditions on $g(t)$, such as the convolution product $y(t)$ is positive $\forall t > 0$?

Thanks!

Comment: What is a "causal" function?

Comment: Actually, I've abused the notation a little. It's a causal impulse response. Basically, $f(t) = 0\, \forall t<0$.

Comment: Taking $g$ positive obviously makes $y$ positive. Otherwise I assume that $g$ must depend on $f$.